# How to solve a step function in Python?

Tags: python, scipy

I am writing an options trading program in Python. The program comes up with trades and then determines the price points of the underlying stock at which a specific trade will be profitable.

**I am going to try to phrase the question so anyone regardless of their options knowledge can provide a solution.**

An example trade consists of buying `n` puts and `y` calls. (Where `n` and `y` are integers). The cost of the trade is to be called the variable `cost_of_trade`

The trade is profitable if `cost_of_trade < profit_from_trade`

---

`profit_of_trade = profit_from_calls  + profit_from_puts`

If the price of the stock is greater than the strike price of the call at expiration then:

`profit_from_calls = (final_stock_price - calls.strike_price) * y)`

else:

`profit_from_calls = 0`

--

If the price of the stock is less than the strike price of the put at expiration then:

`profit_from_puts = (-final_stock_price + puts.strike_price) * n)`

else:

`profit_from_puts = 0`

---

I need to solve the equation where `cost_of_trade == profit_from_trade`. Solving this equation should give me two values. **The fundamental problem I have is that I don't know how to put the equation in terms that python can solve. The `if statement` in the equation that is making things difficult.**

Creating if statements outside of the equation is not really an option. Although it might make sense for this simple example problem, in the real program there are so many different trades and different combinations of trades I would have to write 1000+ `if statements`, which is not something I want to do.

Comment: I really dont understand what is the problem actually.Also where is your functions? is there any _global_ variable?

Answer (score 5):

You can solve most anything you can compute e.g by bisection...:

```
def bisection(f, a, b, TOL=0.001, NMAX=100):
    """
    Takes a function f, start values [a,b], tolerance value(optional) TOL and
    max number of iterations(optional) NMAX and returns the root of the equation
    using the bisection method.
    """
    n=1
    while n<=NMAX:
        c = (a+b)/2.0
        # decomment to learn more about the process
        # print "a=%s\tb=%s\tc=%s\tf(c)=%s"%(a,b,c,f(c))
        if f(c)==0 or (b-a)/2.0 < TOL:
            return c
        else:
            n = n+1
            if f(c)*f(a) > 0:
                a=c
            else:
                b=c
    return None

def solve(y, call_strike, call_premium, n, put_strike, put_premium):
    cost = y * call_premium + n * put_premium
    def net(fp):
        call_profit = max(fp-call_strike, 0)
        put_profit = max(put_strike-fp, 0)
        tot_profit = call_profit * y + put_profit * n
        return tot_profit - cost
    return bisection(net, 0, 2 * max(call_strike, put_strike))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # an example...:
    print solve(12, 20.0, 3.0, 15, 25.0, 2.0)
```

See e.g https://gist.github.com/swvist/3775568 for the original code for `bisection` and other approaches to numerical solutions of arbitrary equations.

Comment: @Jakobovski, glad you liked it!